# how to get windows version from emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23, dot-emacs

how to get the detail version information of windows from emacs.
i am try to invoke "ver" windows command to get version information, but got failed.

```
(call-process "ver")
```

<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or  directory" "ver")
call-process("ver")
eval((call-process "ver"))
eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
eval-last-sexp(nil)
call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(shell-command "ver" t) ;; outputs version in current buffer
```

Comment: (defvar my-windows-version-info (shell-command-to-string "ver"))

Comment: Do note that this may depend on how emacs was launched, depending on how this particular routine was implemented.  If it was done "correctly" - ie, the correct C function was called to get the OS version, then you may get an older OS version than what you're actually running on, for 'program compatibility reasons'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also query system-configuration : <kbd>C-h v system-configuration RET</kbd>

The documentation states:

> On MS-Windows, the value reflects the OS flavor and version on which
>   Emacs is running.

On my laptop, it says `i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600`

Comment: thanks! that's a good way to find out the version of microsoft windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx